# Leftjoin mongodb laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an issue on how to convert mysql query to MongoDB in Laravel

In mysql I have left join query but in laravel-mongodb I don't see same left join query.

mysql query

```
\DB::table('landingpages')->leftjoin('campaigns', 'campaigns.id', '=', 'landingpages.campaign_id')->get();
```

I change in my mongodb

```
\DB::collection('landingpages')->leftjoin('campaigns', 'campaigns.id', '=', 'landingpages.campaign_id')->get();
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have joins. Are you sure it's supported?

Comment: As a clarification: MongoDB DOES support JOINs, it just does them either embedded or manually client side. It is the same though and you can code to replicate JOINs (Yii2 can) within your app. It appears that the mantainer of this library did not think they wanted to add such functionality

Comment: Yes. i know MongoDB not support Join. but i want resolve the problem. Help me resolve the problem. MongoDB support embeded and map/reduce but i don't know use it.

Answer (score 6):

You probably using [jenssegers's mongo db library](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) in laravel. Yes, you can not use Left Join or any kind of join using that library, because mongo db doesn't support joins. By the way, you can do it manually by looping through the result array. Mongodb is not efficient for this kind of joining works.

Comment: I write code to list all record. if i using loop much. It's not good for performent. I use jenssegers mongodb . Other idea ??

Comment: Mongo DB is good for big data but it sucks in some situations and you can not write performance efficient query with it in some cases. You have to face problems if you use a schema less database, thats why mysql is so popular.
see this video, you will get some idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70O3kGUFmgo

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use any kind of 'Join' in mongodb. It is non relational database.

Answer (score 0):

From `Mongo 3.2` onwards you can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) operator to perform left outer join.

**Syntax**

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

In laravel you can use [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) library and make use of [raw expression](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#raw-expressions) to achieve left outer join.

**using mongodb query builder**

```
// Returns the original MongoCursor.
DB::collection('landingpages')->raw((function($collection) {
      return $collection->aggregate([
        [
          '$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'campaigns',
            'localField' => 'campaign_id',
            'foreignField'=> 'id',
            'as' => 'campaign'
          ]
        ]
      ]);
 }));
```

**using moloquent**

```
// Returns a collection of LandingPage models.
LandingPage::raw((function($collection) {
      return $collection->aggregate([
        [
          '$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'campaigns',
            'localField' => 'campaign_id',
            'foreignField'=> 'id',
            'as' => 'campaign'
          ]
        ]
      ]);
 }));
```